# javascript - add milliseconds to counter

Tags: javascript, timer

I would like to know how can i add milliseconds to my JS counter of quiz. At this point the quiz itself only count and look for seconds (in mysql it's a number of seconds, like: 120 (2 minutes), and it's displayed as 02:00). Now i would like to add milliseconds to it. Thanks in advance

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var quiz_timer = 0;

$(window).load(function(){
setInterval('run_timer()',1000 )
})

function run_timer()
{
quiz_timer++;

if(quiz_timer > 60)
{
    sec = quiz_timer%60;
    min = Math.floor(quiz_timer/60);
}
else
{
    sec = quiz_timer;
    min = 0;
}

var timer='';

if(min < 10)
timer = '0';

timer += min;

timer += ':';

if(sec < 10)
timer += '0';

timer += sec;


var timer_h = 'Time: '+timer;//+rand();
$('#quiz_timer').html(timer_h);
$('#quiz_time').val(quiz_timer);
}

function update_quiz()
{
var cnt_questions = parseInt($('#cnt_questions').val());
var cq = parseInt($('#current_question').val());
var op = $('#question_'+cq).find('input[type=radio]:checked').length;

if(op == 0)
{
    alert('You must answer on the question.');
    return false;
}

if(cq < cnt_questions)
{
    $('#question_'+cq).hide();
    $('#question_'+(cq+1)).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#current_question').val(cq+1);
    return false;
}   

$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
document.frm_quiz.submit();
}
</script>
```

And here's the function that input the data in mysql:

```
function timer($quiz_timer)
{
if($quiz_timer > 60)
{
    $sec = $quiz_timer%60;
    $min = floor($quiz_timer/60);
}
else
{
    $sec = $quiz_timer;
    $min = 0;
}

$timer='';

if($min < 10)
$timer = '0';

$timer .= $min;

$timer .= ':';

if($sec < 10)
$timer .= '0';

$timer .= $sec;

return $timer;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding them?

Comment: @putvande I've been searching around for the proper way, but i couldn't find any...

Comment: Well.. for starters.. you need to change your `setInterval` to run every millisecond rather then every second.

Comment: @putvande If i understood it right, 1000 is a second, right, it's 1000ms = 1s, if i make it a hundred instead of 1000, it'll be running every millisec, right? Am i on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var quiz_timer = 0;
    var millisecondFactor = 60;  //lesser this factor, accurate the timer will work
    var sec = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var hour = 0;
    $(window).load(function () {
        setInterval('run_timer()', (1000 / millisecondFactor));
    })

    function run_timer() {
        quiz_timer++;
        millisec = quiz_timer;
        if (millisec > millisecondFactor) {
            sec++;
            quiz_timer = 0;
        }
        if (sec > 59) {
            min++;
            sec = 0;
        }
        if (min > 59) {
            hour++;
            min = 0;
        }
        if (hour > 23) {
            hour = 0;
        }

        var timer = '';

        if (min < 10)
            timer = '0';

        timer += min;

        timer += ':';

        if (sec < 10)
            timer += '0';

        timer += sec;

        timer += ':';

        if (millisec < 10)
            timer += '0';

        timer += millisec;

        var timer_h = 'Time: ' + timer;//+rand();
        $('#quiz_timer').html(timer_h);
        $('#quiz_time').val(quiz_timer);
    }

    function update_quiz() {
        var cnt_questions = parseInt($('#cnt_questions').val());
        var cq = parseInt($('#current_question').val());
        var op = $('#question_' + cq).find('input[type=radio]:checked').length;

        if (op == 0) {
            alert('You must answer on the question.');
            return false;
        }

        if (cq < cnt_questions) {
            $('#question_' + cq).hide();
            $('#question_' + (cq + 1)).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#current_question').val(cq + 1);
            return false;
        }

        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
        document.frm_quiz.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that's working perfectly fine now, i can see the timer is running milliseconds, do you mind checking my edit to see the 2nd part of the code that input data in mysql, for some reason, it inputs all the wrong time...

Comment: well i dont mind.. but u ll have to post it as new question..:p

Comment: great, sure thing, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318651/js-add-timer-in-mysql-as-datetime-with-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Your current way has a very significant flaw: the timing of the setInterval isn't perfect. A much better way to deal with time is to use the Date object, get the start time and then in setInterval compute the elapsed time.

Here is some sample code that should get you on the right track. It only needs you to format the time how you want and you're good to go:

```
/* display the currently elapsed time */
function showTime(){
  var time = formatTime(Date.now() - startTime);
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time;
}

/* format the number of miliseconds how you wish them */
function formatTime(elapsed) {
  var hours, minutes, seconds, milis;

  hours = Math.floor(elapsed/(60*60*1000));
  elapsed -= hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  minutes = Math.floor(elapsed/(60*1000));
  elapsed += minutes * 60 * 1000;

  seconds = Math.floor(elapsed/1000);
  elapsed -= seconds * 1000;

  milis = elapsed;

  return 'H' + hours + ' M' + minutes + ' S' + seconds + ' F' + milis; // change this
}

/* start counting */
var startTime = Date.now();
/* runs every 10ms, but it's hardly noticeable */
var interval = window.setInterval(showTime, 10);

/* stop after a while */
window.setTimeout(function() { window.clearInterval(interval);}, 3000);
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/EqoRezE/1/edit

PS: Date.now() might not be available on your particular target browser. You can find an alternative implementation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: for this time i'll stick with the code i have... I'd really like to understand that code first, before i can move forward. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: No worries. Just keep in mind that it is fundamentally flawed and while the flaw might not be aparent when you deal with seconds, it will haunt you when you increase the granularity. I'll edit my post with some formatting, to help you understand both my code and your original code.

Comment: Thank you very much, i would like to have it working as i'm in the middle of the work right now. I'm facing some problems where users has the same time like 2 seconds, and i have to add milliseconds so i can sort them easier... However, thanks for helping me out, i really appreciate it.