# JS - add timer in mysql as datetime with milliseconds

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, counter

i have the script that count the time for my quiz users, now i would like to know how can i input the date in mysql as milliseconds and display it later that way, instead of seconds only (as it is now.).

Here is what i have:

I would like to know how can i add milliseconds to my JS counter of quiz. At this point the quiz itself only count and look for seconds (in mysql it's a number of seconds, like: 120 (2 minutes), and it's displayed as 02:00). Now i would like to add milliseconds to it. Thanks in advance

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var quiz_timer = 0;
var millisecondFactor = 60;  //lesser this factor, accurate the timer will work
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;
$(window).load(function () {
    setInterval('run_timer()', (1000 / millisecondFactor));
})

function run_timer() {
    quiz_timer++;
    millisec = quiz_timer;
    if (millisec > millisecondFactor) {
        sec++;
        quiz_timer = 0;
    }
    if (sec > 59) {
        min++;
        sec = 0;
    }
    if (min > 59) {
        hour++;
        min = 0;
    }
    if (hour > 23) {
        hour = 0;
    }

    var timer = '';

    if (min < 10)
        timer = '0';

    timer += min;

    timer += ':';

    if (sec < 10)
        timer += '0';

    timer += sec;

    timer += ':';

    if (millisec < 10)
        timer += '0';

    timer += millisec;

    var timer_h = 'Time: ' + timer;//+rand();
    $('#quiz_timer').html(timer_h);
    $('#quiz_time').val(quiz_timer);
}

function update_quiz() {
    var cnt_questions = parseInt($('#cnt_questions').val());
    var cq = parseInt($('#current_question').val());
    var op = $('#question_' + cq).find('input[type=radio]:checked').length;

    if (op == 0) {
        alert('You must answer on the question.');
        return false;
    }

    if (cq < cnt_questions) {
        $('#question_' + cq).hide();
        $('#question_' + (cq + 1)).fadeIn(1000);
        $('#current_question').val(cq + 1);
        return false;
    }

    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    document.frm_quiz.submit();
}
```

Thanks to Vicky Gonsalves ^

And here's the function that input the data in mysql:

```
function timer($quiz_timer)
{
if($quiz_timer > 60)
{
    $sec = $quiz_timer%60;
    $min = floor($quiz_timer/60);
}
else
{
    $sec = $quiz_timer;
    $min = 0;
}

$timer='';

if($min < 10)
$timer = '0';

$timer .= $min;

$timer .= ':';

if($sec < 10)
$timer .= '0';

$timer .= $sec;

return $timer;
}
```

Also here's the table that display the quiz time:

```
<?
require_once 'config.php';


isLoggedIn();


$page = 'top20';

$qry = 'select *  from quiz where user_id="'.$_SESSION['USER_ID'].'" order by id desc limit 1';
$sql = $dbh->prepare($qry);
$sql->execute();
$c_quiz = $sql->fetch();


$qry = 'select a.user_id as userid,a.cnt_correct,a.quiz_time,a.id as q_id,b.* from users b left join quiz a on a.user_id = b.id where  cnt_correct > 0 
    order by cnt_correct desc,quiz_time asc';

$sql = $dbh->prepare($qry);
$sql->execute();
$top = $sql->fetchAll();

$q_ids = array_keys($top);

$inc = 0;

$top20 = array();

foreach($top as $key=>$item)
{
if(array_key_exists($item['userid'],$top20))continue;

$inc++;

//$item = $item[0];

$top20[$item['userid']] = array($inc,$item['cnt_correct'],$item['q_id']);

}

foreach($top20 as $key=>$item){

if($c_quiz['id'] == $item[2])
{
    $in_rating = true;
    $top_place = $item[0];
    $top_score = $item[1];
    break;
}

}

//echo '<pre>';print_r($top20);

//if($in_rating)

if($action == 'quiz')
{
if($c_quiz['cnt_correct'] == 0)
setMessage('Niste odgovorili tačno ni na jedno pitanje');
//elseif($c_quiz['cnt_correct'] == 0)
//setMessage('Your last score is: 0');
else
setMessage('Imali ste ukupno:: '.$c_quiz['cnt_correct'].' tačnih odgovora. Nalazite se na: '.$top_place.' mestu');
}


//else
//setMessage('Score: '.$c_quiz['cnt_correct'].' Time taken:     '.timer($c_quiz['quiz_time']));

//setMessage('Your last score is: '.$c_quiz['cnt_correct'].' Time taken: '.timer($c_quiz['quiz_time']));


//echo '<pre>';print_r($top);
require_once 'header.php';

?>

 <div id="container">
  <div class="content home top20">
    <h2 class="animated">Top lista:</h2>
<div id="top20_table">
<table cellpadding=0 style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);" width="750px">
<tr align="left">
    <th width="70" align="left">Mesto</th>
    <th width="200" align="left">Ime</th>
    <th width="150" align="left">Rezultat</th>
    <th width="100" align="left">Vreme</th>
</tr>
   <?
   $inc = 0;

   $top20 = array();

foreach($top as $key=>$item){

if(in_array($item['userid'],$top20))continue;

$top20[] = $item['userid'];

$inc++;
if($inc == 20)break;

//$item = $item[0];

//print_r($item);die;
?>
<tr align="left">
    <td><?=$inc?>.</td>
    <td><?=$item['firstname'].' '.$item['lastname']?></td>
    <td><?=$item['cnt_correct']?></td>
    <td><?=timer($item['quiz_time'])?></td>
</tr>
<?
}
?>
</table>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<?
require_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: its pretty confusing...I dont understand here, are you trying to run timer on php server?

Comment: Yes, i'm running it on php server Vicky

Comment: uh..it will not run on php server as it is running on javascript..u ll have to capture timestamp when ur php script starts loading and capture timestamp at the submission of form and take out the difference which will give you timeduration...OR you can directly submit time from your javascript to php server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed whole script and used the date instead. Thanks everyone.